# Return only once but returning multiple times

Tags: reactjs

Trying to display * once if required is true in that ingredientgroups but displaying twice

```
ingredientGroups: Array(2)
[ {isRequired: true,  in: "E", sort: 10}, {isRequired: true, in: "y", sort:1}]
```

```
<div>
    {this.props.ingredientGroups.map((ingredientGroup) => {
     return (
       <div id={ 'ff' + ingredientGroup.ingredientGroupId }
         key={ ingredientGroup.ingredientGroupId }
       >     
         {
          (ingredientGroup.isRequired === true) ?
            '*': ''
          }
       </div>  
     );
    })}
</div>
```

```
expected: *
```

```
actual :  *  
          *
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why 2 `*` are being printed is because of this condition:

```
(ingredientGroup.isRequired === true)
```

Within your `ingredientGroups` array, both objects have `isRequired` as `true`, which is why both are returning true when you iterate through `this.props.ingredientGroups` using [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and when the values of `isRequired` are passed through the above if statement. Hence, 2 `*`s are being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking why you get two `'*'` on runtime as a result of the code you have, it's because you're mapping through the ingredientGroups array using [map() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and printing either a `*` or nothing **for each element in the array.** The array has two elements.

That will result in the code inside the map() function being run for each element and the array and you will end up with two `'*'` being printed.

Please refer to [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought was that you are mapping through the array. and if its set to true it gives a dot. As there are two items in the array evaluating to true it gives you two *.
To test i ran the code

```
class Application extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return <div>
    {this.props.ingredientGroups.map((ingredientGroup) => {
     return (
       <div id={ 'ff' + ingredientGroup.ingredientGroupId }
         key={ ingredientGroup.ingredientGroupId }
       >     
         {
          (ingredientGroup.isRequired === true) ?
            '*': 'd'
          }
       </div>  
     );
    })}
</div>;
  }
}

/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
React.render(<Application  ingredientGroups = {[ {isRequired: true,  in: "E", sort: 10}, {isRequired: true, in: "y", sort:1}]} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

This got the same issue as you, but the code below works.

```
class Application extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return <div>
    {this.props.ingredientGroups.map((ingredientGroup) => {
     return (
       <div id={ 'ff' + ingredientGroup.ingredientGroupId }
         key={ ingredientGroup.ingredientGroupId }
       >     
         {
          (ingredientGroup.isRequired === true) ?
            '*': 'd'
          }
       </div>  
     );
    })}
</div>;
  }
}

/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
React.render(<Application  ingredientGroups = {[ {isRequired: true,  in: "E", sort: 10}]} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

If you would like to keep two items in the array I suggest doing one of the following:

```
ingredientGroups: Array(2)
[ {isRequired: false,  in: "E", sort: 10}, {isRequired: true, in: "y", sort:1}]
```

**OR**

```
<div>
    {this.props.ingredientGroups.map((ingredientGroup) => {
     return (
       <div id={ 'ff' + ingredientGroup.ingredientGroupId }
         key={ ingredientGroup.ingredientGroupId }
       >     
         {
          (ingredientGroup.in === "E") ?
            '*': ''
          }
       </div>  
     );
    })}
</div>
```

Comment: In the code that works you have used only one object as input.But using two object need to print only one *

Comment: What do you mean not working? Because the code above should cause only one * to show up. If by not working you mean there is only one object then yes there is only one object if you would like a second object didn’t set one of the items to false. The array looks through both items checks to see if isRequired is true and then does something accordingly.